# Мапинг промежуточной таблицы в hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Если процедура и после вызова процедуры я получаю результат с промежуточной таблицы. Как мне этот результат преобразовать в объект?

Comment: Смотря что за объект (Entity, не ентити) и каким API (Hibernate, JPA) пользуетесь.

Comment: Hibernate, обычный маппинг в POJO объект.